# Video Recording Hangs on IMFSinkWriter->Finalize();

Tags: c++, c++11, video, ms-media-foundation

I have an issue when finalizing a video recording into an .mp4 using Media Foundation where the call to `IMFSinkWriter->Finalize();` hangs forever. It doesn't always happen, and can happen on almost any machine (seen on Windows server, 7, 8, 10). `Flush()` is called on the audio and video streams before hand and no new samples are added between `Flush` and `Finalize`. Any ideas on what could cause `Finalize` to hang forever?

Things I've tried:

- Logging all `HRESULT`s to check for any issues (was already checking them before proceeding to the next line of code)

> Everything comes back as `S_OK`, not seeing any issues

- Added the `IMFSinkWriterCallback` on the stream to get callbacks when
  the stream process markers (adding markers every 10 samples) and finishes `Finalize()`

> Haven't been able to reproduce since adding this but this would give the best information about what's going on when I get it working.

- Searched code samples online to see how others are setting up the
  Sink Writer and how `Finalize()` is used

> Didn't find many samples and it looks like my code is similar to the ones that were found

- Looked at encoders available and used by each system including version of the encoder dll

> Encoders varied between AMD H.264 Hardware MFT Encoder and H264 Encoder MFT on machines that could reproduce the issue. Versions didn't seem to matter and some of the machines were up to date with video drivers.

Here are some code samples without any `HRESULT` checking (that doubled the amount of code so I took it out)

Building the sink sample:

```
CComPtr<IMFAttributes> pAttr;
::MFCreateAttributes( &pAttr, 4 );
pAttr->SetGUID( MF_TRANSCODE_CONTAINERTYPE, GetFileContainerType() );
pAttr->SetUINT32( MF_LOW_LATENCY, FALSE ); // Allows better multithreading
pAttr->SetUINT32( MF_SINK_WRITER_DISABLE_THROTTLING, TRUE ); // Does not block
pAttr->SetUINT32( MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS, TRUE );

m_pCallback.Attach( new MFSinkWriterCallback() );
pAttr->SetUnknown( MF_SINK_WRITER_ASYNC_CALLBACK, m_pCallback );

::MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL( m_strFilename.c_str(), NULL, pAttr, &m_pSink );

if ( m_pVideoInputType && m_pVideoOutputType )
{
   m_pSink->AddStream( m_pVideoOutputType, &m_dwVideoStreamId );
   // Attributes for encoding?
   CComPtr<IMFAttributes> pAttrVideo;

   // Not sure if these are needed
   //::MFCreateAttributes( &pAttrVideo, 5 );

   m_pSink->SetInputMediaType( m_dwVideoStreamId, m_pVideoInputType, pAttrVideo );
}
if ( m_pAudioInputType && m_pAudioOutputType )
{
   m_pSink->AddStream( m_pAudioOutputType, &m_dwAudioStreamId );
   // Attributes for encoding?
   CComPtr<IMFAttributes> pAttrAudio;

   // Not sure if these are needed
   //::MFCreateAttributes( &pAttrAudio, 2 );
   //pAttrAudio->SetGUID( MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_AAC );
   //pAttrAudio->SetUINT32( MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, 16 );

   m_pSink->SetInputMediaType( m_dwAudioStreamId, m_pAudioInputType, pAttrAudio );
}
m_pSink->BeginWriting();
```

Stopping the recording sample:

```
if ( m_dwVideoStreamId != (DWORD)-1 )
{
   m_sink->Flush( m_dwVideoStreamId );
}
if ( m_dwAudioStreamId != (DWORD)-1 )
{
   m_sink->Flush( m_dwAudioStreamId );
}

m_sink->Finalize();
```

Comment: Do you have a minimal source code so we can check. Because it doesn't always happen, it seems to be a critical section/wait for event issue.

Comment: Hey @mofo77 I added the code used for building the sink and stopping the recording above. Let me know if there are any other parts of the code you'd like to see.

Comment: Are you sure you want to flush before finalize ? Because last samples will be dropped...

Comment: @mofo77 I had the same problem, and after I removed the call to Flush() before Finalize() there were no more deadlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of situation where a Media Foundation application can hang :

- Calling MFShutDown/CoUninitialize when using Media Foundation objects.
- Using a GUI, and doing bad use of windows message pump in multithreaded application.
- Bad use of MTA/STA components.
- Bad use of critical section/wait for event function.
- Forget to call EndXXX() function when BeginXXX() function are used.
- Bad use of Callback function.
- Forget to call AddRef when necessary, and releasing the object used by another thread.
- A bug in Media Foundation (there are some on Windows Seven).
- and so on...

When i say a minimal source code, i mean, isolate the source code that do the encoding process, and provide it to Github if it's too large. It's better if we can compile and try the source code, because deadlock are difficult to find.

Comment: The problem ended up being no use of critical sections around places the sink was used. Providing minimal source code would have taken longer than I wanted to put into this at this time. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Anthony Could you please tell more about these places? I don’t use my media sink, I construct it and pass into the writer. Then the writer uses it, I don’t call any sink methods. MS says I must first shutdown writer only then call Shutdown on the sink, and it’s writer who hangs.