# Video Recording Hangs on IMFSinkWriter->Finalize

Tags: c++, windows, windows-10, h.264, ms-media-foundation

I’ve implemented custom IMFMediaSink for use with sink writer. Works OK, receives h264 video samples. I don’t have any container, I’m consuming raw h264 video samples. I have not implemented custom writer, I'm using [MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfreadwrite/nf-mfreadwrite-mfcreatesinkwriterfrommediasink) API to wrap my custom media sink into a framework-provided writer.

I’m unable to implement graceful shutdown, `IMFSinkWriter::Finalize()` never returns. When I implemented `IMFSinkWriterCallback`, `IMFSinkWriter::Finalize()` returns immediately but my `IMFSinkWriterCallback::OnFinalize` was never called.

The problem reproduces in 100% tests with both nvenc and MS software encoder.

Writer attributes:

```
MF_LOW_LATENCY = TRUE
MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS = TRUE (1)
MF_READWRITE_DISABLE_CONVERTERS = FALSE (2)
MF_SINK_WRITER_DISABLE_THROTTLING = TRUE
MF_SINK_WRITER_D3D_MANAGER
MF_SINK_WRITER_ASYNC_CALLBACK
```

(1) Tried both, same result

(2) Need the converters because nvenc only supports YUV and I have RGB textures on input.

Output media type (it’s fixed, I’m using the built-in handler created by `MFCreateSimpleTypeHandler` API).

```
MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE = MFMediaType_Video
MF_MT_SUBTYPE = MFVideoFormat_H264
MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE = MFVideoInterlace_Progressive
MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE = 40*1000*1000
MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE = { 3840, 2160 }
MF_MT_FRAME_RATE = { 60, 1 }
MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO = { 1, 1 }
```

Input media type:

```
MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE = MFMediaType_Video
MF_MT_SUBTYPE = MFVideoFormat_RGB32
MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE = MFVideoInterlace_Progressive
MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE = { 3840, 2160 }
MF_MT_FRAME_RATE = { 60, 1 }
MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO = { 1, 1 }
```

When not using IMFSinkWriterCallback, here’s a call stack at the time of hang:

```
ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForSingleObject@12 ()
KernelBase.dll!WaitForSingleObjectEx()
mfreadwrite.dll!CMFSinkWriter::InternalFinalize(void)
mfreadwrite.dll!CMFSinkWriter::Finalize(void)
```

MFTrace doesn’t have anything related to finalize even with `-k All`:

```
13700,3C60 19:01:25.79566 CMFTransformDetours::ProcessOutput @02EA6E3C failed hr=0xC00D6D72 MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT
13700,2A98 19:01:25.80250 CMFTransformDetours::ProcessOutput @1A6CEF38 Stream ID 0, Sample @1C244F30, Time 1216ms, Duration 16ms, Buffers 1, Size 12441600B, MFSampleExtension_CleanPoint=1;MFSampleExtension_Interlaced=0
13700,2098 19:01:25.80254 CMFTransformDetours::ProcessInput @02EA6E3C Stream ID 0, Sample @1C244F30, Time 1216ms, Duration 16ms, Buffers 1, Size 12441600B, MFSampleExtension_CleanPoint=1;MFSampleExtension_Interlaced=0
13700,2A98 19:01:25.80256 CMFTransformDetours::ProcessOutput @1A6CEF38 failed hr=0xC00D6D72 MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT
13700,2A98 19:01:25.80266 CMFTransformDetours::ProcessMessage @1A6CEF38 Message type=0x00000001 MFT_MESSAGE_COMMAND_DRAIN, param=00000000
13700,2A98 19:01:25.80267 CMFTransformDetours::ProcessOutput @1A6CEF38 failed hr=0xC00D6D72 MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT
13700,2098 19:01:25.81669 CMFTransformDetours::ProcessOutput @02EA6E3C Stream ID 0, Sample @1FB68CF8, Time 1216ms, Duration 16ms, Buffers 1, Size 680B, {2B5D5457-5547-4F07-B8C8-B4A3A9A1DAAC}=1;{73A954D4-09E2-4861-BEFC-94BD97C08E6E}=12166667 (0,12166667);{9154733F-E1BD-41BF-81D3-FCD918F71332}=65535;{973704E6-CD14-483C-8F20-C9FC0928BAD5}=1;MFSampleExtension_CleanPoint=0;{B2EFE478-F979-4C66-B95E-EE2B82C82F36}=16 (0,16)
13700,82C 19:01:25.81674 CMFTransformDetours::ProcessOutput @02EA6E3C failed hr=0xC00D6D72 MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT
13700,82C 19:01:25.81674 CMFTransformDetours::ProcessMessage @02EA6E3C Message type=0x00000001 MFT_MESSAGE_COMMAND_DRAIN, param=00000000
13700,82C 19:01:25.81674 CMFTransformDetours::ProcessOutput @02EA6E3C failed hr=0xC00D6D72 MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT
13700,1F54 19:01:27.24237 CKernel32ExportDetours::OutputDebugStringA @ D3D11 WARNING: Process is terminating. Using simple reporting. Please call ReportLiveObjects() at runtime for standard reporting. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN] 
13700,1F54 19:01:27.24255 CKernel32ExportDetours::OutputDebugStringA @ D3D11 WARNING: Live Producer at 0x0311D91C, Refcount: 13. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
```

Warnings about live D3D resources are expected as I terminated the process after the hang.

Any ideas what’s going on? I think the writer probably waits for these SPS/PPS magic blobs to arrive but it never happens. Is there a way to instruct the h264 encoder to output SPS/PPS somewhere?

Comment: Can you maybe post the code in github or some place? Also, when using the `IMFSinkWriterCallback` does the `IMFSinkWriter::Finalize` exit with `S_OK` ?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis That’s work for hire, I’ll ask the client but I don’t think they gonna allow it.

Yes, when passing IMFSinkWriterCallback, IMFSinkWriter::Finalize returns `S_OK` and it’s very fast. That’s how I’ve implemented a workaround: I pass callbacks when constructing the writer, when finished I call Finalize, wait for some time for IMFSinkWriterCallback::OnFinalize to arrive (using a Win32 event), if it doesn’t happen I proceed anyway, Release() the writer COM interface, then call Shutdown() and Release() on my IMFMediaSink object.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve implemented custom IMFMediaSink, so i suppose you 've also implemented IMFStreamSink.

Doing this in the usual way with Mediafoundation, you have circular COM reference between IMFMediaSink and IMFStreamSink. That's why the Shutdown method from IMFMediaSink interface exists.

If a program that uses your custom MediaSink does not call Shutdown at the right place, there will be memory leaks.

From your IMFSinkWriterCallback problem, we don't have enough information to find where the problem is.

Also it is not clear about "custom IMFMediaSink" and "IMFSinkWriter". Are you also implementing a IMFSinkWriter...

**EDIT1**

Just two things :

[MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfreadwrite/nf-mfreadwrite-mfcreatesinkwriterfrommediasink)

Call CoInitialize(Ex) and MFStartup before calling this function.

When you are done using the media sink, call the media sink's IMFMediaSink::Shutdown method. (The sink writer does not shut down the media sink.) Release the sink writer before calling Shutdown on the media sink.

do you release interfaces correctly ?

[IMFSinkWriter::Finalize](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/api/mfreadwrite/nf-mfreadwrite-imfsinkwriter-finalize)

Internally, this method calls IMFStreamSink::PlaceMarker to place end-of-segment markers for each stream on the media sink.

Do you handle this message (MFSTREAMSINK_MARKER_ENDOFSEGMENT) ?

We don't know how you handle CriticalSection/Event/CircularReference, so it's hard to found the problem.

**EDIT2**

> Is there a way to instruct the h264 encoder to output SPS/PPS somewhere?

Normally, for h264 video format, you need to get the attributes MF_MT_MPEG_SEQUENCE_HEADER (BLOB type) when SetCurrentMediaType is called on your IMFStreamSink (assuming you implements IMFMediaTypeHandler).

**EDIT3**

Could you provide the real one (this is how i think the app should be) :

[image: topology and dataflow]

I don't remember if your custom sink creates a mp4 file. If it is, in the IMFSinkWriter::Finalize, you have to generate ftpy/moov atom.

**EDIT4**

Also you can read this : [Video Recording Hangs on IMFSinkWriter->Finalize();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767688/video-recording-hangs-on-imfsinkwriter-finalize/33878513#33878513)

With no source code, this is the only answer i can give.

Comment: Yes I’ve also implemented custom stream sink. No I’m using framework-provided writer, created by `MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink` API.

I can’t remember where I saw that but I’m under the impression that I must first shutdown the writer only then the sink. I have no problem shutting down my sink. It’s the writer that has this problem.

Comment: Remarks in the `MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink` article say “The sink writer does not shut down the media sink… Release the sink writer before calling Shutdown on the media sink”.
And the documentation for `IMFSinkWriter::Finalize` says “If you do not call Finalize, the output from the media sink might be incomplete or invalid”.

Correct me if I’m wrong, but from these two articles, the correct shutdown sequence (implying I want complete and valid video stream) must be the following: `writer->Finalize(); writer->Release(); sink->Shutdown();` It’s the first of them that hangs.

Comment: “Do you handle this message?” yes I’m getting the message but I’m not doing anything special, just check for shutdown and return S_OK. Should I do more?
“do you release interfaces correctly?” I do, but the problem happens earlier than that, before releasing the sink.
“assuming you implements IMFMediaTypeHandler” I do not, I’m using a handler created by MFCreateSimpleTypeHandler. But I’m not sure the problem is with SPS/PPS, that’s an idea based on my previous experience with MF.

Comment: In my test app I have one more sink writer downstream, created by another API, `MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL`. That second writer doesn’t encode anything, it writes .mp4 files from already encoded h264 MF samples. That downstream writer finalizes OK and produces valid video files. It’s the intermediate sink writer that hangs on Finalize().

Comment: It's not clear how your app works. Could you show the complete topology with a drawing. In the finalize method, your sink writer should writes all output sample, if any. If you can produce out sample, writes them, if not nothing to do.

Comment: My library captures RGB pics from external API. Uses sink writer (with automatically constructed MFTs) to resize & and encode into h264 using GPU hardware. Uses custom media sink (with a custom stream sink) to grab h264 samples. My test client for the library receives h264 samples, uses another sink writer to produce mp4 file (this one without any custom sinks). The library’s for streaming, this test app is only to debug & test this capture/encode library.
When I call finalize method on the writer, the only call my custom sink received is end segment marker.

Comment: With your explanation, i don't understand the dataflow from begin to end. Could you make a drawing of the topology and the dataflow ? I don't understand how all the component are connected, and how the dataflow is.

Comment: You say you have an the intermediate sink writer (the custom one). you can't have a custom sink writer between a MFT and another sink writer. It should be a MFT...

Comment: I don’t have topology, I don’t have session, and I don’t have custom MFTs.

Data flow is custom API -> first sink writer (library calls MF-implemented `IMFSinkWriter::WriteSample` on the first writer, created by `MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink`) -> custom sink (MF calls my `IMFStreamSink::ProcessSample`) -> second sync writer (client app calls `IMFSinkWriter::WriteSample` on the second writer, created by `MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL`) -> mp4 file (second writer writes samples without my code involved anywhere).

Comment: Obviously, shutdown needs to work in the same order: first shutdown writer #1, then custom sink, then writer #2. It’s the first shutdown step that fails with this issue, before trying to shutdown the custom sink.

Comment: When i talk about topology and dataflow, it is just to visualize how your app behaves. Topology is just a word to represent where MediaFoundation Object are. I will show you a drawing in EDIT3, you will tell me if it is like your app is. Like i said, i'l not sure, even after your explanation.